# React PWA Service Worker is not registering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, progressive-web-apps, server-side-rendering

I am trying to setup project in React with Server Side Rendering and PWA.
I have setup React with Server Side Rendering but when I am trying to add PWA I am not able to do.

This is my project structure.
[image]

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    client: './src/client.js',
    bundle: './src/bundle.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" }
    ]
 }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-poc",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "react-poc",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "yarn build && node index.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "author": "Piyush Jain",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/register": "^7.8.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  }
```

In my src folder i created a file worker.js

```
// Flag for enabling cache in production
var doCache = false;

var CACHE_NAME = 'pwa-app-cache';

// Delete old caches
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  const currentCachelist = [CACHE_NAME];
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys()
      .then(keyList =>
        Promise.all(keyList.map(key => {
          if (!currentCachelist.includes(key)) {
            return caches.delete(key);
          }
        }))
      )
  );
});

// This triggers when user starts the app
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  if (doCache) {
    event.waitUntil(
      caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
        .then(function(cache) {
          fetch('manifest.json')
            .then(response => {
              response.json();
            })
            .then(assets => {
              // We will cache initial page and the main.js
              // We could also cache assets like CSS and images
              const urlsToCache = [
                '/',
                assets['bundle.js']
              ];
              cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
            })
        })
    );
  }
});

// Here we intercept request and serve up the matching files
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  if (doCache) {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        return response || fetch(event.request);
      })
    );
  }
});
```

then I added this in html

```
<script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('worker.js').then(function(registration) {
            console.log('Worker registration successful', registration.scope);
          }, function(err) {
            console.log('Worker registration failed', err);
          }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
          });
        });
      } else {
        console.log('Service Worker is not supported by browser.');
      }
    </script>
```

But when I am trying to run app I am getting below error.

**Worker registration failed TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/') with script ('http://localhost:3000/worker.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.**

Comment: you can't test PWA with the development servers. you need to build and test with a localhost HTTP server or easily deploy to a firebase hosting to test with a mobile. it'll be easy for you.

Comment: Your worker script needs to be available via an HTTP GET request. Note that since none of your code imports `worker.js` module, it won't be bundled neither into `client.js` nor into `bundle.js` and basically won't be part of your app once it's built. Correct answer depends on your dev server setup, but perhaps try moving `worker.js` to assets directory and adjust path in `serviceWorker.regster` call accordingly?